# Access control allow origin issue raised in Angular 6 on post operation

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm able to do the 'Get' operation without CORS issue but unable to do the 'Post' operation in Angular 6. Getting a 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I'm tried in two ways. but issue not fixed.

```
  createCustomer(Customer) {
console.log(Customer);
return this.http.post(this._global.baseUrl + '/Customer/CreateCustomer', Customer, { 
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"        
  })      
});
```

}

2nd way:

```
      createCustomer(Customer) {
    console.log(Customer);
    return this.http.post(this._global.baseUrl + '/Customer/CreateCustomer', JSON.stringify(Customer), this._global.httpOptions)
  }
```

Header class:

```
 export class AppGlobals {
readonly baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:50264/api';
  readonly httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    })    
  };
}
```

ASP.Net Core API Code:
Startup.cs Code:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowCors",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:50264")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            );
        });
        services.AddMvc();   




 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler();
        }

        app.UseCors("AllowCors");
        app.UseMvc();
        //app.Run(async (context) =>
        //{
        //    throw new Exception("Example exception");
        //});
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
// POST: api/Customer/CreateCustomer    
    [EnableCors("AllowCors")]
    [ActionName("CreateCustomer")]        
    public JsonResult CreateCustomer([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
```

These are the error screens. [API log screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQFpj.jpg)

Screen 2:
[API Log Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBADa.jpg)

Postman screen:
[Postman screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqIWk.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you'll need to whitelist your domain on the server.

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code **500*** is key here. When there's an exception in your ASP.NET Core project, the CORS headers are cleared. You should try and find out why an exception is being thrown.

Comment: You don't need to set `"Content-Type": "application/json"`, Angular does this by default. You also should not stringify the JSON object before you send it in a POST request if the service endpoint is expecting a JSON object.

Comment: Hi, @KirkLarkin Thank you for your reply. 
But the API is working fine in postman.

Comment: Hi @Brandon, Thank you for your reply.
Could you please give me a sample code for better understand. I'm fresher in Angular. So please give me a clear and complete code.

Comment: All that proves is that you’re doing something different when using Postman. Have a look at your server logs when the problem occurs and you’ll find out what’s going wrong. Don’t treat this as a CORS issue until you’ve done that.

Comment: @murthy, @kirk-larkin is correct. Postman doesn't make XHR requests unless you specifically add the `X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest` headers. Add those to your request and see if it breaks.

Comment: Hi @Brandon, kirk_Larkin 
please see the attached screenshots once.

Comment: Use the following guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1, and make sure to use correct domains !

Comment: @murthy I don't see the `X-Requested-With` header in your Postman requests. If that isn't present, these are normal GET requests, and aren't the same as what's coming from Angular's HttpClient.

Comment: Still the issue is not fixed. but changed the error text. could you please referrer once. 

**POST http://localhost:50264/api/Customer/CreateCustomer 500 (Internal Server Error)**

**create:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:50264/api/Customer/CreateCustomer' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
customer.service.ts:29 Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error**

Comment: These are the my asp.net core project package references.
**<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>**

Comment: **<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>**

Comment: You're getting a `500 Internal Server Error` - It's internal so the details are not reported to the client (which would be a security risk). Look at the server's error logs to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just i changed my code to:

```
createCustomer(customer: Customer) {
let body = {
  "name": customer.name,
  "email": customer.email,
  "primaryPhone": customer.primaryPhone,
  "alternatePhone": customer.alternatePhone,
  "address1": customer.address1,
  "address2": customer.address2,
  "address3": customer.address3,
  "city": customer.city,
  "state": customer.state,
  "country": customer.country,
  "zip": customer.zip,
};
return this.http.post(this._global.baseUrl + '/Customer/CreateCustomer', body, { 
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"        
  })      
});
```

Comment: In my personal experience, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is depends not only the CORS issue. In my above answer i passed the data to Json format. after that my CORS issue is fixed. I spend so much of time on both API & Angular. but that issue is only in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how currently we are doing,

We have a `HttpOptionsClass` which contains below code

```
export const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  })
};
```

And we have a service class which inject `HttpClient` service and below is our `POST` action code

```
saveCustomer (customer: Customer ): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Customer>(
      environment.baseUrl + "/customers",
      customer,
      httpOptions
    );
  }
```

Below is out ASP.Net Core Web API backend with CORS handling

API Controller

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]s")]

public class CustomerController : Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Customer customer)
        {
            // your code goes here
            return Created($"api/customers/{customer.Id}", customer);
        }
}
```

appsettings.json class

```
{
  "AllowedOrigins": [
    "http://localhost:4200"
  ],
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
}
```

Startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", policy =>
                {
                    var corsUrlSection = Configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins");
                    var corsUrls = corsUrlSection.Get<string[]>();
                    policy.WithOrigins(corsUrls)
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
        }
```

Access from customer component

```
  this.service.saveCustomer(this.customer : Customer).subscribe(
    result => {

    },
    error => {

    }
  );
```

First, check whether you hit the endpoint. If you get 500 error and CORS issue, there is a high chance that something is wrong with your code inside action

Comment: createCustomer(customer: Customer): Observable<any> {
    let body = {
      "name": customer.name,
      "email": customer.email,
      "primaryPhone": customer.primaryPhone,
      "alternatePhone": customer.alternatePhone,
      "address1": customer.address1,
      "address2": customer.address2,
      "address3": customer.address3,
      "city": customer.city,
      "state": customer.state,
      "country": customer.country,
      "zip": customer.zip,
    };

Comment: return this.http.post(this._global.baseUrl + '/Customer/CreateCustomer', body, this._global.httpOptions).map(this.extractData)    
      .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);    
  }

After that changes. its working fine.

Comment: @murthy I forgot to add that code. I have updated the answer. So I think now you have a working code. If this was helpful please make this as the correct answer. Will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Change the origin to `http://localhost:4200`.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowCors", builder => 
         builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // instead of 50264
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
    );
}
```

Or add it to the list

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowCors", builder => 
         builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:50264", "http://localhost:4200")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
    );
}
```

This will solve the CORS part. If you are still getting the HTTP 500 error, the error happens somewhere in your CreateCustomer method.

Comment: Hi, @Ivan 
Its not a CORS issue. just I'm sending data from Angular in let body ={"name": customer.name} and then changed the CreateCustomer method body content.

Comment: Hi, @Damith, 
Did you understand what i'm saying?
I'm not able to post the answer. If you understand my solution could you please post the answer based on my changes.